# Portlet lifecycle and init

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, portlet

It is not clear to me when is a `Portlet`'s `init` method called. Is it called when the container instantiated or when a first request to the portlet comes?
Does it have the same behavior as the `Servlet#init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the container. From [the Portlet 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286):

> **PLT.5.2.1 Loading and Instantiation**
>
> The portlet container is responsible for loading and instantiating
>   portlets. The loading and instantiation can occur when the portlet
>   container starts the portlet application, or delayed until the portlet
>   container determines the portlet is needed to service a request.
>
> ...
>
> **PLT.5.2.2 Initialization**
>
> After the portlet object is instantiated, the
>   portlet container must initialize the portlet before invoking it to
>   handle requests.

Comment: For servlet's this also depends on the `load on startup`, right?Is this also applicable for portals?

Comment: IIRC, portlets do not support this feature. There are listener types you can use if you want to be notified of application context creation.

Comment: I thought that somehow portlet is build on top of servlets

Comment: A portlet container might be a servlet which serves pages that contain portlets; portlets are more like widgets within a page. A portlet is not a servlet.